# How to escape json character (Double quote, Comma ) in php

Tags: php, json, excel

I am doing php project using  php excel.. I have already created php class for read excel sheet. That class return  simple json string .. That json string i will use for  show data table in web page. But that json string can't include any json character . Therefore user can not input some json character in excel sheet . Otherwise so many errors create when encoding json string .

What is the best way prevent this problem?
have some good way to read excel sheet (Using library)?

Comment: did you ty  addslashes()  or stripslashes() ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Slash should be added after the quotations (escaping it)

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O'Reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O\'Reilly?
echo addslashes($str);
?>
```

Here you are an approach suitable for JSON.

```
function json_string_encode($str) {
    $callback = function($match) {
        if ($match[0] === '\\') {
            return $match[0];
        } else {
            $printable = array('"' => '"', '\\' => '\\', "\b" => 'b', "\f" => 'f', "\n" => 'n', "\r" => 'r', "\t" => 't');
            return isset($printable[$match[0]])
                   ? '\\'.$printable[$match[0]]
                   : '\\u'.strtoupper(current(unpack('H*', mb_convert_encoding($match[0], 'UCS-2BE', 'UTF-8'))));
        }
    };
    return '"' . preg_replace_callback('/\\.|[^\x{20}-\x{21}\x{23}-\x{5B}\x{5D}-\x{10FFFF}/u', $callback, $str) . '"';
}
```